# Acceleration in $x$ and $y$ directions of a pendulum swinging?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, acceleration

If there is a pendulum that gets released and only moves in two dimensions, what would it’s acceleration be in the x and y directions, meaning at what rate is the velocity changing in the x and y directions? If it is possible to derive a formula, how would it be derived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it is possible to derive a formula, how would it be derived?

You would use Newton's second law. This is the standard procedure for problems like these

1) Draw a free body diagram that includes all forces acting on the object

2) Choose a coordinate system to work in

3) Use Newton's second law $\sum \mathbf F=m\mathbf a$

4) Use algebra to determine the acceleration

I will leave it up to you to follow these steps for the simple pendulum. It is a good exercise to do.

Comment: @AshtonHalat Yes that is usually a good idea. The vector equation in my answer means $\sum F_x=ma_x$ and $\sum F_y=ma_y$